# Excel - how to select the top 10 duplicates only if 10 or more are present

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a 500k line excel like the sample below:

```
ref,         RSRQ,     Signal,    SNR,    TestDate 

ST782347,     -13,     -116,     40,    01/04/2020

ST782347,      -9,     -111,    110,    22/02/2020

ST782347,     -10,     -115,     70,    22/02/2020

ST782347,      -9,     -111,    110,    22/02/2020

ST782349,     -10,     -110,     90,    22/02/2020

ST782349,     -10,     -114,     50,    22/02/2020
```

Now the "ref" can have 1 to 800 equal values, but I only want the most recent 10 if it has 10 or more, otherwise should be discarded. I have been stuck here for a couple of days now, any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to do this process once only?

1. order by date, the most recent up (you should be able to use the filter on this,
   maybe your data is already ordered?)
2. run a count on ref
3. mark and filter results below 10

see image for steps 2 and 3

Hope this helps!

[image: countifs and if]
PS: always helps to give a sample of your data in Excel format, so that we don't have to reproduce it... cheers

Comment: Thank you Celine. I tried to paste, but it was pasting as image, i thought it would be better as text...